# How to insert static and dynamic data as same (multiple)rows into MySQL database from a PHP form in one submission

Tags: php, mysql, forms

****NOTE**: I have asked this question on this site and have been suggested a solution, the logic of which I do not get, and am still unable to implement it. This is therefore an edited version of the initial question to make it more concise and perhaps clearer so I could hopefully get more responses. I have also changed the title  to what I hope will be more meaningful.**

I have started learning PHP along with MySQL(complete newbie), and I have created a database with questions and options tables as part of a  quiz app project to help me learn . I thought it would be  a good learning  experience to populate the database by submitting the questions and options through a PHP processed form.

The problem I am having  in a nutshell is this,I have the following form:

[dataentry form]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S0gu.png
    Question section of form(variable rows) with single field constant metadata

```
        <div class="questinfo">
            <div class="questmetadata">

            <select name="questfield[0][subject_id]">
                <option>BA</option>
                <option>MY</option>
                <option>PA</option>
                <option>BB</option>
                <option>CC</option>
                <option>UA</option>
                <option>HM</option>
                <option>CG</option>

            </select>
             <input name="questfield[0][chapter_id]">

            <input name="questfield[0][topic_id]">
             <input name="questfield[0][is_active]">
            <select name="questfield[0][type]">
                <option>P</option>
                <option>L</option>
            </select>

            <select name="questfield[0][level]">
                <option>1<option>
                <option>2 II<option>
                <option>3<option>
            </select>

            </div>

            <div class="questrow">
            <input  name="questfield[1][questid]">
            <input  name="questfield[1][numero]">
            <textarea  name="questfield[1][question]"></textarea>
            </div>

<div class="questfield">
            <input  name="questfield[2][id]">
            <input  name="questfield[2][numero]">
            <input name= "questfield[2][is_active]">
            <textarea  name="questfield[2][question]"></textarea>
        </div>


            <div class="questrow">
            <input  name="questfield[3][questid]">
            <input  name="questfield[3][numero]">
            <textarea  name="questfield[3][question]"></textarea>
            </div>
```

Options section of form; variable option fields with unique corresponding metadata fields.

```
    <div class="optionfield">
        <input type="text" name ="optionfield[0][optid]">
        <input type="text" name ="optionfield[0][choice]">
        <input type="text" name ="optionfield[0][question_numero]">
        <input type="checkbox" name ="optionfield[0][is_answer]">

        </div>

        <div class="optionfield">
        <input type="text" name ="optionfield[1][optid]">
        <input type="text" name ="optionfield[1][choice]">
        <input type="text" name ="optionfield[1][question_numero]">
        <input type="checkbox" name ="optionfield[1][is_answer]">
        </div>


        <div class="optionfield">
        <input type="text" name ="optionfield[2][optid]">
        <input type="text" name ="optionfield[2][choice]">
        <input type="text" name ="optionfield[2][question_numero]">
        <input type="checkbox" name ="optionfield[2][is_answer]">
        </div>


        <div class="optionfield">
        <input type="text" name ="optionfield[3][optid]">
        <input type="text" name ="optionfield[3][choice]">
        <input type="text" name ="optionfield[3][question_numero]">
        <input type="checkbox" name ="optionfield[3][is_answer]">
        </div>


This is the corresponding PHP;  only the first row is entered into the question table but the options table has all four rows.(because unlike for the questions section of the form, all the column entries in the options table by necessity must correspond to a distinct field in the form)

    $optsql=" INSERT INTO 

    options


    SET
    optid=:optid,
    question_numero=:question_numero,
    choice=:choice,
    is_answer=:is_answer,
    answer_explanation=:answer_explanation";

$questsql=" INSERT INTO questions

            SET
            questid=:questid,
            numero=:numero,
            question=:question,
            subject_id=:subject_id,
            chapter_id=:chapter_id,
            topic_id=:topic_id,
            type=:type,
            level=:level,
            is_active=:is_active

        ";


$optstmt=$clsdb->prepare($optsql);
$queststmt=$clsdb->prepare($questsql);



    foreach($_POST['optionfield'] as $optinput){

    $optdata= array(

        'optid'=>$optinput['optid'],
        'question_numero'=>$optinput['question_numero'],
        'choice'=>$optinput['choice'],
        'answer_explanation'=>$optinput['answer_explanation'],
        'is_answer'=>$optinput['is_answer']);

$optstmt->execute($optdata);


}

foreach($_POST['questfield'] as $questinput){

$questdata= array(

        'questid'=>$questinput['questid'],
        'numero'=>$questinput['numero'],
        'question'=>$questinput['question'],
        'subject_id'=>$questinput['subject_id'],
        'chapter_id'=>$questinput['chapter_id'],
        'topic_id'=>$questinput['topic_id'],
        'type'=>$questinput['type'],
        'level'=>$questinput['level'],
        'is_active'=>$questinput['is_active']);

        $queststmt->execute($questdata);

}
```

The form is in two sections: the questions and corresponding options respond to one submit button but insert data into different(option and question)tables in the database. In the above image, I  have four rows of fields in the questions section of the form(please forgive the styling or lack thereof). The first row is for the metadata, and the three rows beneath that(each ending with the textbox) represent three separate question rows to be entered in the database.The metadata row contains data that I want to fill respective columns in the three question rows once submitted to the database.With my current PHP code,  only one question row inserts along with the appropriate metada. What I want is the following:

[desire results]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LpJP.png

But with the metadata filled out(instead of the zeroes).The metadata should vary based on what is selected in the form for various submissions but be the same for any number of rows inserted at the same time with a given submission.

Based on the above code, a user named  Martin Law suggested the following solution:

```
foreach($_POST['questfield'] as $key => $value){
//static vars(metadata)
$questdata[$key] = $value;
foreach($_POST['optionfield'] as $key => $value){
    //changing vars(answers)
    $questdata[$key] = $value;
    //Write to db
    $stmt->execute($query);
}
```

}

However, the above code returns a notice error:"arrow to string conversion", which I found out was because $questdata which I passed into the execute function is a  multidimensional array. Moreover, I do not understand the logic of this code.I had separate insert queries and prepared statements for question and options, but in the above code only one statement and query($query ) is implied.What should the "$query" be? Also in the code,there is a nested foreach loop passing the "optionfield" array and assigning the elements to the $questdata, how does that fit into the solution to the problem which primarily concern the questions table? Would anyone please elaborate on the logic of  Martin's solution and how I can implement it successfully based on the data provided, or offer an original solution? Thank you.

Comment: Your inputs are sent to the server as an array. Arrays you need to loop through to get the values. To see this - on your php use var_dump( $_POST) to see the data being sent through.

Comment: If you could illustrate with example data that would be great, particularly current results and desired results.

Comment: Kayb, my example was not supposed to be copy paste code. $query is the 'INSERT INTO questions' query, wich you need to build from the questdata array. INSERT INTO questions SET questid=$questdata['questid'], numero=$questdata['numero'],........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider breaking up the metadata from the `questfield` array as they remain static for the form. And in the insert query, re-use those scalar `$_POST` fields along with the `questfield` values that are dynamic (*questid*, *numero*, *question*):

**HTML**

```
<div class="questmetadata">
  <select name="subject_id">
      <option>BA</option>
      <option>MY</option>
      <option>PA</option>
      <option>BB</option>
      <option>CC</option>
      <option>UA</option>
      <option>HM</option>
      <option>CG</option>
  </select>

  <input name="chapter_id">

  <input name="topic_id">
  <input name="is_active">

  <select name="type">
      <option>P</option>
      <option>L</option>
  </select>

  <select name="level">
      <option>1<option>
      <option>2 II<option>
      <option>3<option>
  </select>
</div>
```

With change be sure to adjust indices for `questfield`:

```
<div class="questrow">
   <input  name="questfield[0][questid]">
   <input  name="questfield[0][numero]">
   <textarea  name="questfield[0][question]"></textarea>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
...
foreach($_POST['questfield'] as $questinput){

    $questdata= array(
        'questid'=>$questinput['questid'],         // DYNAMIC FIELDS
        'numero'=>$questinput['numero'],
        'question'=>$questinput['question'],
        'subject_id'=>$_POST['subject_id'],        // STATIC FIELDS
        'chapter_id'=>$_POST['chapter_id'],
        'topic_id'=>$_POST['topic_id'],
        'type'=>$_POST['type'],
        'level'=>$_POST['level'],
        'is_active'=>$_POST['is_active']
    );

    $queststmt->execute($questdata);
}
```

Comment: Parfait, I took a little break away from the screen, and tried your solution again this morning; it worked ''parfaitment"! Thank you immensely. To Martin Law, I learned  from your post about populating the array using the syntax you proposed.  I selected parfait's solution since I could implement it without further inquiry. Thank you both. I am still learning, and am eager to reach the point where I can make a similar contribution in the future. @Martin, if you don't mine contacting me privately,  I am still interested in how I could have achieved my goal with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand your question. But if you have data that you need to write to the database that does not change for any of the fields, just exclude them from the foreach loop. Allso if your table var names match your form field names you can save yourselves allot of typing by populating variables like this:

```
foreach($_POST['questfield'] as $key => $value){
    //static vars(metadata)
    $questdata[$key] = $value;
    foreach($_POST['optionfield'] as $key => $value){
        //changing vars(answers)
        $questdata[$key] = $value;
        //Write to db
        $stmt->execute($query);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.In this form, I could add any number of "questfields"(comprising just the quest_numero, id , and the question).All these question fields will be entered as rows in the database when the foreach loop runs once I hit submit. My issue is that the static portion with the same  metadata already mentioned would have to fill in their corresponding columns in the rows entered into the database by the foreach while the code for said static data remains out of the loop.

Comment: Kayb, Then this answer would still work for you. Solution from Parfait should work as well.

Comment: To both Martin Law and Parfait, I appreciate your help a lot, unfortunately I have not been able  to get it to work. Martin, your suggestion gave me a notice error:"array to string conversion", and a bit research showed it is because I  could not pass a multidimensional ($questdata)array to the execute function.What should $query be?  @Parfait, I tried your solution and got a SQL syntax error. Any further help will be greatly appreciated; I apologize for being such a newbie.